# Running csh script from bash script

Tags: bash, csh

I am writing a script that requires a initial setup.
the setup is in the form of csh script that has many artifacts on the environment variables.
right now when i'm executing the csh from within the bash, the variables inside the subshell of the bash are left unchanged.

**example:**

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo $PATH
setevnvar.csh -dir $ROOT_DIR/
echo $PATH
```

in this example I would to see that the PATH variable is changed after running the csh script (it is one of the results)

would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: A `csh` script (which should have an extension like `.csh`, if any, not `.sh`) cannot directly set variables in a `bash` script.

Comment: When you say `is in the form of csh script that has many artifacts on the environment variables` --> The environment variables under `csh` or `bash`?

Comment: the variables are set inside the csh

Comment: @YardenOren: So if I understand right, you want to run a `csh` script which changes some `bash` environment variables for you?

Comment: @Inian yes! i want the .csh to change the variables that are in the subshell of the .sh script

Comment: @YAO: What purpose is that going to solve? If you change the variables in the sub-shell? It is not going to take effect. Perhaps you need to re-think your use-case

Comment: @Inian: i'm writing a script to periodicly run some function that requires this setup.

Comment: @YAO: What is the line in the csh script that you think will change the `$PATH` in `bash`? Can you share it?

Comment: sorry, i can't share it. i usually run this script with "source setevn" and it appends to the PATH

Comment: @YAO: Refer my answer below. See if it helps

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to modify the variables of a shell from any child process.  Since launching `csh` from `bash` launches a child process, there is no way that can be done.

Options you have :

- Convert your `csh` script to `bash`, and `source` it from your `bash` script.
- Convert your `bash` script to `csh`, and again `source` the other script
- Make sure the variables you need are marked for `export` in the `csh` script, and launch your bash script from inside the `csh` script (which may or may not work for your specific need), thereby turning things inside out
- Merge the code from both scripts to have a single (`bash` or `csh`) script

"Sourcing" is done with a `.` or the (non-POSIX) `source` builtin.  For instance :

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo $PATH
. setevnvar.converted_to_bash -dir "$ROOT_DIR/"
echo $PATH
```

"Sourcing" causes the current process to read commands from an other file and execute them as if they were part of the current script, rather than starting a new shell to execute that other file.  This is why variable assignments will work with this method.

Please note I added double quotes to your `"$ROOT_DIR/"` expansion, to protect for the case where it would contain special characters, like spaces.

Comment: thanks! so if I'll have two csh scripts, than the source command will affect the the outside shell (after the script terminates)?

Comment: You must have two scripts run by the same interpreter (can be `csh` if you want), but you *must* call the script by sourcing it, as shown above, if not you will have the same issue.  "Sourcing" causes the current process to read commands from an other file, as if they were part of the current script, rather than starting a new shell to execute that other file.

Comment: As a matter of interest, `source` is not `bash` specific, it comes from `csh`!   It's effect is unspecified in POSIX.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks for the clarification!